# ipython regex replace \r\n[*] with *

Tags: regex, replace, jupyter-notebook

I have a text file designed like this:

```
TEXT
*TEXT;;
```

I now want to merge the lines and replace `\r\n[*]` with `*`. This works in Notepad++ with the regex `\r\n[*]`, but this regex does not work when I try to use it in ipython.

Can you please tell me which regex I will need to use?

Comment: did you try without `\r`? i.e. `\n[*]`

Comment: I tried the following: print line.replace("\n[*]", "") This did not work out.

Comment: Your newline can also be only `\r`. So try something like `\r?\n[*]` or `[\r\n]{1,2}[*]`

Comment: In `line.replace(x, y)`, `x` is a literal string, not a regex. You need to use the `re` module, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
In [11]: import re

In [12]: text = "TEXT\r\n*TEXT;;"

In [14]: re.sub(r'\r\n[*]', '*', text)
Out[14]: 'TEXT*TEXT;;'
```

Please note the `r` (raw string) before the regex string: it is necessary so that escape sequences are preserved unescaped and correctly passed to the underlying regex compiler.

Comment: Actually, the `r` prefix isn't needed in this special case (because the regex escape sequences `\r` and `\n` happen to map exactly to the string escape sequences `\r` and `\n`), but it's good practice nevertheless. +1

Comment: If i try to execute it like this import csv
`import re
with open(FILENAME) as f:
   for line in f:
print re.sub(r'\r\n[*]', '*', line)
`
It will not work and I get an error message

Comment: It won't work because text get splitted at `\n` in the `for line in f` part, so `\r` and `*` will be separed into different strings (and your regex will never match).

Comment: Ok so I want to edit a big csv file where this occures several times. So I will need a script for merging these lines. So I understand the problem I will need to replace the string in the file and not per line but how can I do this?

Comment: You should [mmap the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454456/how-do-i-re-search-or-re-match-on-a-whole-file-without-reading-it-all-into-memor).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *ipython*, but try this RegExp:

```
/(\r?\n|\r\n?)\*/g
```

[Here](http://regexr.com?383kj) it worked.