# How to find required word in novel in python?

Tags: python, string, list, text, split

I have a text and I have got a task in python with reading module:

Find the names of people who are referred to as `Mr. XXX`. Save the result in a dictionary with the name as key and number of times it is used as value. For example:

- If Mr. Churchill is in the novel, then include `{'Churchill' : 2}`
- If Mr. Frank Churchill is in the novel, then include `{'Frank Churchill' : 4}`

The file is .txt and it contains around 10-15 paragraphs.

Do you have ideas about how can it be improved? (It gives me error after some words, I guess error happens due to the reason that one of the `Mr.`  is at the end of the line.)

```
orig_text= open('emma.txt', encoding = 'UTF-8')
lines= orig_text.readlines()[32:16267]
counts = dict()
for line in lines:
    wordsdirty = line.split()
    try:
        print (wordsdirty[wordsdirty.index('Mr.') + 1])
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: If you are asking for people to improve your code, go check out [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text = "When did Mr. Churchill told Mr. James Brown about the fish"
m = [x[0] for x in re.findall('(Mr\.( [A-Z][a-z]*)+)', text)]
```

You get:

```
['Mr. Churchill', 'Mr. James Brown']
```

To solve the line issue simply read the entire file:

```
text = file.read()
```

Then, to count the occurrences, simply run:

```
Counter(m)
```

Finally, if you'd like to drop `'Mr. '` from all your dictionary entries, use `x[0][4:]` instead of `x[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using regex and capturing group.

Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) for reference, in this scenario you might want to do something like

```
# retrieve a list of strings that match your regex
matches = re.findall("Mr\. ([a-zA-Z]+)", your_entire_file)  # not sure about the regex

# then create a dictionary and count the occurrences of each match
# if you are allowed to use modules, this can be done using Counter
Counter(matches)
```

To access the entire file like that, you might want to map it to memory, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454456/how-do-i-re-search-or-re-match-on-a-whole-file-without-reading-it-all-into-memor)

Comment: You don't deal with names like Mr. Tom Smith

Comment: @rudolfovic true, I didn't consider that scenario when writing my answer